# bash: verify that untaring was successful

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

Is there a way to verify in a bash script wheter `tar -xvf foo.tar -C /destination` was successfull or not?

My current bash script looks like this:

```
if [[ tar -xvf foo.tar -C /destination ]]; then
 echo "ok"
else
 echo "not ok"
fi
```

Unfortunaletly I get the following error:

```
verify.sh[124]: syntax error: unexpected operator/operand '-xvf'
```

Is there a better way to verify it?
Why Im not allowed to use -xvf?

Answer (score 2):

`[[` is used for evaluating conditional expressions, not executing arbitrary commands. (`[[` itself *is* a command, though a so-called compound command that is syntactically distinct from a simple command.)

Just drop the brackets.

```
if tar -xvf foo.tar -C /destination; then
```

Whether a 0 exit status from `tar` indicates the type of success you are looking to verify is another question.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is: `if command; then command; fi`. Just

```
if tar -xvf foo.tar -C /destination; then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

> Why Im not allowed to use -xvf?

The `[[ tar -xvf foo.tar -C /destination ]];` is executing command `[[` with 6 arguments. The `-xvf` is invalid operator for `[[`, so the command shows you an error message.